# UIView way of turning off Touch events

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, uiview

Is there a way turn off touch events that use a UIView class?
I'm looking in the class ref, but nothing seems to stick out.

Comment: `UIView` objects by default don't allow user interaction in the first place. Are you using a concrete subclass?

Comment: hmm if we are talking about [userInteractionEnabled](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html) the default value is yes.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Uncheck "User Interaction Enabled" in the interface designer of Xcode to disable any kind of interaction for a particular UIView. In code it is `view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;`. This will also disable interaction for the subviews of that view.